# Group dicts by values using functional programming approach

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

Given a list of group dicts from `regex.findall()`:

```py
[{'short_name': 'f1', 'long_name': 'ae123'}, {'short_name': 'f2', 'long_name': 'ae123'}, {'short_name': 'f3', 'long_name': 'x89zy'}, {'short_name': 'f4', 'long_name': 'bc00'}, {'short_name': 'f5', 'long_name': 'bc00'}]
```

I'd like to group those dicts by 'short_name' key, but I got curious to know how I can do that using functional programming techniques in Python.

My code so far is:

```py
def parse_fonts(style):
    sheet = parse_stylesheet(style, skip_comments=True, skip_whitespace=True)

    values_by_long_name = {}

    fonts = map(
        lambda x: FONT_REGEX.search(x.serialize()).groupdict(),
        sheet[1:]
    )

    values_by_long_name = {}

    for font in fonts:
        values_by_long_name.setdefault(
            font['long_name'], []).append(font['short_name'])

    return values_by_long_name
```

The code above returns something like:

```py
[{'long_name': 'ae123', 'short_name': ['f1', 'f2']}, {'long_name': 'x89zy', 'short_name': ['f3']}, {'long_name': 'bc00', 'short_name': ['f4', 'f5']}]
```

How can I achieve the same without using for loops/list comprehension and, if possible, in only one chain of functions calls, like `a(b(c(d(x))))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is probably what I'd go with in Python, and it's not un-functional per se -- in the sense that a purely functional implementation is still going to follow the same logic:

- fold over the input list, with a dict / map accumulator
- for each (key, value) pair, check if the key exists in the map
- update the map (i.e. return a new map), appending the value if the key exists, and otherwise inserting a new singleton [value] for the key

I guess you could use `itertools.groupby` in Pyton, but it's not very satisfying as you still need a helper to get the same output shape:

```py
import itertools

lst =[{'short_name': 'f1', 'long_name': 'ae123'},
      {'short_name': 'f2', 'long_name': 'ae123'},
      {'short_name': 'f3', 'long_name': 'x89zy'},
      {'short_name': 'f4', 'long_name': 'bc00'},
      {'short_name': 'f5', 'long_name': 'bc00'}]

def regroup(groups):
    """Regroup groupby result."""
    return [{'long_name': key, 'short_name': [g['short_name'] for g in group]}
            for key, group in groups]

g = regroup(itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x['long_name']))

print(g)
```

... which outpus:

```py
[{'long_name': 'ae123', 'short_name': ['f1', 'f2']}, {'long_name': 'x89zy', 'short_name': ['f3']}, {'long_name': 'bc00', 'short_name': ['f4', 'f5']}]
```

On a syntactic level, it's true that with functional languages you can get terser, like this example in Haskell:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as M


pairs = [("f1", "ae123"), ("f2", "ae123"), ("f3", "x89zy"), ("f4", "bc00"), ("f5", "bc00")]

group :: Ord b => [(a, b)] -> M.Map b [a]
group = M.fromListWith (++) . map swap
  where
    swap(a, b) = (b, [a])
```

... which, when run interactively produces:

```hs
*Main M> group pairs
fromList [("ae123",["f2","f1"]),("bc00",["f5","f4"]),("x89zy",["f3"])]
```

If you're interested in functional programming in Python, I'd focus on reasoning about types with `mypy` and limiting the use of side effects, as the syntax will generally be more verbose. (Note that list comprehensions are quite functional -- the equivalent of the `map` function, which applies some function to each value in the list without changing its shape.)

Comment: Thank you, perfect explanation